# How do I specify DECIMAL and DATE formats in rswag/swagger request specs for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, swagger, swagger-ui

```
post('create user') do
  tags 'Jobs'
  consumes 'application/json'
  parameter name: :user, in: :body, schema: {
    type: :object,
    properties: {
      title: { type: :string },
      description: { type: :string },
      date: { type: :datetime  },
      budget: { type: :decimal },
      awarded: { type: :boolean }
    },
  required: [ 'title', 'description' ]
}
  response(201, 'created') do

    after do |example|
      example.metadata[:response][:content] = {
        'application/json' => {
          example: JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
        }
      }
    end
    let(:user) { { title: 'foo', description: 'bar' } }
    run_test!
  end
end
```

I've implemented my request as above, but the output in the Swagger UI says

```
Unknown type: datetime
Unknown type: decimal
```

The rswag docs for Rails don't give a list of how to specify types - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is part of swagger/openapi. Check the [data types](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#string) documentation; there are a limited number of data types.

You want something closer to this:

```
date: { type: :string, format: :datetime }
awarded: { type: :string, format: :decimal }
```

Note: decimal isn't a "real" format, but format is an open value so you can use anything supported by the tools you're using. You might use the `format` annotation along with a `pattern` match to ensure it's a decimal.